# Python using multiprocessing to plot and save in one Figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-multiprocessing

Can I plot the separate processing in one same figure? For example the code blow can only save the last plot in figure.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('agg')
from multiprocessing import Pool
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def f111(a,b,fig):
    plt.plot(a,b,'ro')
    plt.savefig('test.jpg')

if __name__=='__main__':
    fig=plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
    p=Pool(8)
    for i in range(8):
        p.apply_async(f111,args=(1+i*6,6+i*6,fig))
    p.close()
    p.join()
```

Answer (score 1):

@NaiveVincent. It seems clear that each process is saving its own plot, but you're using the same name for all the figure. Therefore, the last plot is the one that remains since the previous are overwritten. If you want to save the different name for each process, you can then proceed as follows:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('agg')
from multiprocessing import Pool
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def f111(a,b,fig, filename):
    plt.plot(a,b,'ro')
    plt.savefig(filename)

if __name__=='__main__':
    fig=plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
    p=Pool(8)
    for i in range(8):
        filename = 'test' + str(i+1) + '.jpg'
        p.apply_async(f111,args=(1+i*6,6+i*6,fig, filename,))
    p.close()
    p.join()
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Maybe my question is not clear. My purpose is to save all separate plot in one same figure.

Answer (score 0):

I believe 'fig' you pass to apply_async in this case becomes a copy, not a pointer to the initially created 'fig' object, what's happening here is that every process saves (from it's own copy of fig) to test.jpg with only it's own plotted data from

```
plt.plot(a, b, 'ro')
```

And the one you get to see is the proces that happens to finish last.

Is it essential that you do this in separate processes? something as simple as this would be better to plot in a simple loop.

If however you need to do heavy calculations in the pool you might want to store the results in a multiprocessing.Array which allows you to write data from all child processes and can be later used in the parent process. In this way you can plot to a single figure in you parent process which is easy but still have the benefit of fast parallel calculations

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('agg')
from multiprocessing import Pool, Array
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def f111(i, a, b, arr_a, arr_b):
    calc_value_a = a * 2
    calc_value_b = b * 2
    arr_a[i] = calc_value_a
    arr_b[i] = calc_value_b


if __name__=='__main__':
    fig=plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
    arr_a = Array('i', range(8))
    arr_b = Array('i', range(8))
    p=Pool(8)
    for i in range(8):
        p.apply_async(f111, args=(i, 1+i*6, 6+i*6, arr_a, arr_b))
    p.close()
    p.join()
    plt.plot(arr_a, arr_b, 'ro') 
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I also understand it in the same way. I am look for the solution to save all plot in one Figure.  It is essential for me. The loop is too big in my project, and each step need some time.

Comment: Is there a way for you to do all the heavy processing in the pool but then return the found data back to the parent process and do the plotting there? Or is it somehow necessary to plot in the child processes?

Comment: Actually, I tried what you mentioned. It is faster than without multiprocessing. I want faster. In your opinion, after multiprocessing for data, do the sample plot from the returned dataset with one core. Is this the best solution?

Comment: If you want to plot in a single figure there is no clean way i think with matplotlib from different processes. So if you pass for example an 'Array' from the multiprocessing module you can write output to that (it's multiprocessing safe) and use the result on your original process. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue for the proper way to implement it.